# Formula for sequence of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition, pattern-matching

I am trying to find a somewhat nice general formula for the following sequence.

$2,2,6,6,10,10,14,14,\dots$

I found one on wolfram alpha, however I am not sure how to derive it; I am also wondering if there is a more simple version.

Wolfram Alpha Solution: $(-1)^n(2(-1)^nn+(-1)^{n+1}-1)$

Comment: If nothing works, then one can always go to Lagrange Interpolation.

Comment: @QiZhu: mh, on how many points ? Can you show us the result ?

Comment: Mhm, you're right. Of course, it does not work in this instance - I was too quick to answer... Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

$$4\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor+2\ ?$$

Comment: How did you derive this? It is exactly the form I am after

Comment: @babynewton: generate and transform the sequence $0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,\cdots$.

Answer (score 0):

> however I am not sure how to derive it; I am also wondering if there is a more simple version.

$$\begin{array}{cccccccc}
& 2 & 2 & 6 & 6 & 10 & 10 & 14 & 14 & \dots \\ 
= & \color{blue}{1}\color{red}{+1} & \color{blue}{3}\color{red}{-1} & \color{blue}{5}\color{red}{+1} & \color{blue}{7}\color{red}{-1} & \color{blue}{9}\color{red}{+1} & \color{blue}{11}\color{red}{-1} & \color{blue}{13}\color{red}{+1} & \color{blue}{15}\color{red}{-1} & \ldots
\end{array}$$

So take odd numbers and alternate between adding and subtracting $1$:

$$\color{blue}{2n-1} \color{red}{- (-1)^n}$$